# Erros no Geckodriver auto-installer (webdriver para web-scraping)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, geckodriver

Bom dia,

Fiz um script de web-scraping usando Selenium, pandas, bf4 and GeckoDriver

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager  

url = "https://example/url/target"
    
    option = Option()
    option.headlers = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Public\geckodriver.exe')

driver.get(url)
[...]
```

Com este código o programa **funciona 100%** mas como eu preciso que seja uma aplicação portável (transferir para outros computadores) eu não quero que o usuário tenha que especificar manualmente o caminho do Geckodriver e muito menos ter que baixar isso.

---

O Geckodriver tem um auto-installer mas em todas as formas que tento fazer da erro, procurando aqui no fórum achei esta alternativa (e o erro)

```
url = "https://example/url/target"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=rGeckoDriverManager().install())

driver.get ("https:www.python.org")
driver.get(url)
```

Result: `ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host = 'api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025186487F98>: Failed to stabilish a new connection: [Errno 11001 getaddrinfo failed',))`

---

Também tentei seguindo o: https://pypi.org/project/geckodriver-autoinstaller/#description :

```
import geckodriver_autoinstaller
geckodriver_autoinstaller.install()  

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

Result: `<urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>`

---

Todas estas opções testei também com `socket.getddrinfo('localhost', 8080)` e também usando o Git hub Token no `os.environ['GH_TOKEN'] = 'exampletoken'`

Alguém sabe por que eu não estou conseguindo automatizar a instalação do driver?

---

Estou usando:
W10 64 bits,
Firefox ultima versão,
Libs e anaconda ultima versão,
Python = 3.6,
Internet com VPN (computador empresarial)

Comment: Esses erros apontam para um problema de conexão. Provavelmente você está atrás de um proxy corporativo.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo testei aqui e funcionou sem problemas desta forma:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

navegador = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
navegador.get('http://www.python.org')
```